# Cannot select "None" subtitle option on ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I use `ExoPlayer` to play videos in my app, subtitles of which I fetch through some API endpoint. They show up just fine, with the first one autoselected, however, when trying to disable the subs, by clicking the "None" option provided by `ExoPlayer` it does nothing.

This is how I create the `SubtitleConfigurations` list(subs are all .vtt):

```
val list = arrayListOf<MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration>()

captions.forEach { caption ->
  caption.resourceUrl?.let { url ->
    val subtitle = MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(url.toUri())
      .setMimeType(MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT)
      .setLanguage(caption.lang)
      .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
      .build()
    list.add(subtitle)
  }
}
```

the subtitles' list then gets fed into the `MediaItem` like this:

```
val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
  .setUri(url.toUri())
  .setSubtitleConfigurations(generateSubtitles())
  .build()

with(exoPlayer) {
  setMediaItem(mediaItem)
  prepare()
  play()
}
```

Now, when the video starts, it starts with subtitles enabled and the none option available, like this:

> - None
> - English

but it just cannot be clicked, it just does nothing.

However, I tried to add a "None" option manually directly to the list, like this:

```
if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
  val noneOption = MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(Uri.EMPTY)
    .setLanguage("none")
    .setMimeType(MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT)
    .build()
  list.add(0, noneOption)
}
```

and the added none option works, to disable the subs, however, now the subtitle dialog list looks like this:

> - None
> - None
> - English

and only the second(manually added) option works, not the default none.

How does one either fix the first none option to work, or hide it so only the manually none option remains?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone in the future has this problem, the problem that was causing this issue in my case was that the ExoPlayer had a preferred language set by default to use locale, so it wouldn't let me change the language.

What I did to solve it was override the parameters of the TrackSelector when initializing so it had no preferred language, in the lines of:

I have the `ExoPlayer` instance in the `ViewModel`, so I declare the variables like this:

```
private val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(App.instance)
private val parametersBuilder = trackSelector.buildUponParameters().apply {
    clearOverridesOfType(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT)
    setPreferredTextLanguage(null)
}
private val parameters = parametersBuilder.build()
val exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
```

Then I `initialize` them like this:

```
init {
    trackSelector.parameters = parameters
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(App.instance)
        .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
        .build()
}
```

Hope this helps